Node group failed to join the eks cluster
I'm tring to create eks cluster in my organization (hub&spoke)
I'm not allowed to use any public way and therefore im using vpc endpoint from the vpc to the managed aws eks master
I'm using cdk (ts)
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct, IConstruct } from "constructs";
import * as ec2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";
import * as iam from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import * as eks from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-eks";
import * as elbv2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";

export class CustomizeEKS extends cdk.Stack {
  private ctags: { key: string; value: string; props?: cdk.TagProps }[] = [];
  private vpc: ec2.IVpc;
  private cluster: eks.Cluster;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    this.ctags = [];

    this.createVPC();
    this.vpc && this.CreateVPCEndpoints();
    this.vpc && this.CreateEKS();
    this.TagResource();
  }

  /**
   * Create VPC with 64 IP addresses
   * 2 Subnets in 2 AZs
   * No NAT Gateways
   * No Internet Gateway
   * No Public Subnets
   */
  private createVPC() {
    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "test-vpc", {
      cidr: "10.0.0.0/26",
      natGateways: 0,
      createInternetGateway: false,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          cidrMask: 27,

          name: "application",
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        },
      ],
      availabilityZones: ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b"],
      vpcName: "EksVpc",
    });

    this.ctags.push({ key: "Environment", value: "Test" });
    this.ctags.push({
      key: "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb",
      value: "1",
      props: { includeResourceTypes: ["AWS::EC2::Subnet"] },
    });
    this.ctags.push({
      key: `kubernetes.io/cluster/${this.vpc.vpcId}`,
      value: "test",
      props: { includeResourceTypes: ["AWS::EC2::Subnet"] },
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create VPC Endpoints for S3, EC2, ECR, and EKS
   */
  private CreateVPCEndpoints() {
    const endpointList: ec2.IInterfaceVpcEndpointService[] = [
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.S3,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.STS,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.EC2,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR_DOCKER,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ELASTIC_LOAD_BALANCING,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.XRAY,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.CLOUDWATCH_LOGS,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.EKS,
      ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.EKS_AUTH,
    ];

    const getName = (s: ec2.IInterfaceVpcEndpointService) =>
      s.name
        .replace(/\$\{Token\[TOKEN\.\d+\]\}+\.*/, "")
        .replace(/\$\{Token\[TOKEN\.\d+\]\}+\.*/, "")
        .replace(/\$\{Token\[TOKEN\.\d+\]\}+/, "");

    for (const endpoint of endpointList) {
      const i = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, getName(endpoint), {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: endpoint,
        subnets: this.vpc.selectSubnets({
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        }),
        privateDnsEnabled: false,
      });
      cdk.Tags.of(i).add("name", getName(endpoint));
    }
  }

  private CreateEKS() {
    const mastersRole = new iam.Role(this, "AdminRole", {
      assumedBy: new iam.AccountRootPrincipal(),
    });
    mastersRole.addManagedPolicy(
      iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AdministratorAccess")
    );

    const workersRole = new iam.Role(this, "WorkerRole", {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("ec2.amazonaws.com"),
    });
    workersRole.addManagedPolicy(
      iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy")
    );
    workersRole.addManagedPolicy(
      iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
        "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
      )
    );
    workersRole.addManagedPolicy(
      iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy")
    );

    this.cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, "EksCluster", {
      version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_30,
      vpc: this.vpc,
      vpcSubnets: [{ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS }],
      mastersRole,
      clusterName: "TestCluster",
      defaultCapacity: 2,
      endpointAccess: eks.EndpointAccess.PRIVATE,
    });

    new eks.Nodegroup(this, "NodeGroup", {
      cluster: this.cluster,
      instanceTypes: [new ec2.InstanceType("t3.medium")],
      minSize: 1,
      maxSize: 3,
      desiredSize: 2,
      nodegroupName: "TestNodeGroup",
      nodeRole: workersRole,
    });
  }

  private TagResource() {
    for (const tag of this.ctags) {
      cdk.Tags.of(this).add(tag.key, tag.value, tag.props);
    }
  }
}

const app = new cdk.App();
new CustomizeEKS(app, "TestEks", {
  env: {
    account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
    region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
  },
});
app.synth();

and i got this error
TestEks | 15/21 | 10:53:55 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EKS::Nodegroup                   | NodeGroup (NodeGroupA8D4A5C5) Resource handler returned message: "[Issue(Code=NodeCreationFailure, Message=Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster, ResourceIds=[i-0274bb8f9fb1b6832, i-0d0e264f0213e6660])] (Service: null, Status Code: 0, Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 173dd5fa-2fff-b64c-ebb1-41572005871b, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
TestEks | 15/21 | 10:53:55 | CREATE_FAILED        | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-KubernetesResource | EksCluster/AwsAuth/manifest/Resource/Default (EksClusterAwsAuthmanifest4F460A9B) Resource creation cancelled
TestEks | 15/21 | 10:53:55 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::EKS::Nodegroup                   | EksCluster/NodegroupDefaultCapacity (EksClusterNodegroupDefaultCapacityA81E70F9) Resource creation cancelled

I were expect the eks workers find their way to the eks masters using the vpc endpoint
as i see they didn't use the endpoint since there is no logs in the endpoints

Try without creating and specifying the nodeRole - CDK will create one for you with the necessary permissions. This is to rule out an IAM issue.
